# Question about time system of first order system

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics

[image]

can anyone plz explain this next step? how this has been done

Comment: I don't agree with that 1/(1+ST)S is right.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha doesn't agree either. The first one inverts to 1 - e^(-t/T) second one inverts to e^(-t/T)/T + 1

Comment: What do C(s) and R(s) mean? I assume, they are not intended to be capacitor and resistor, are they?

Comment: Looks like a typo to me after reordering terms ...

Comment: C(s) and R(s) are the Laplace transforms of the system and excitation respectively.